# How to write SPARQL Query to retrieve data about Tourism from DBpedia?

Tags: semantic-web, sparql, dbpedia

How to write SPARQL Query to retrieve data about Tourism from DBpedia??
Can any one elaborate it( how to write SPARQL Query & what are the things i should already know to start with SPARQL), as i am completely new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example SPARQL query for a starter can be (if you are impatient, [jump to the result set](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?uri%20?txt%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?uri%20rdfs%3alabel%20?txt%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?txt%20bif%3acontains%20%22Tourism%22%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on)):

```
SELECT ?uri ?txt WHERE {
              ?uri rdfs:label ?txt .
              ?txt bif:contains "Tourism" .
             }
```

For a very good and gentle introduction to Semantic Web (with lots of very nice SPARQL examples) please see

- [Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist, Second Edition: Effective Modeling in RDFS and OWL](http://mkp.com/news/semantic-web-for-the-working-ontologist-2nd-edition-effective-modeling-in-rdfs-and-owl-by-dean-allemang-james-hendler)

And in order to learn how to integrate Semantic Web technologies into your custom software applications, this is a very good resource (with lots of example using Semantic Web APIs / toolkits such as Jena):

- [A Developer’s Guide to the Semantic Web](http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+&+information+retrieval/book/978-3-642-15969-5)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the W3C spec [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/), but you also have plenty of tutorials to look online if you search for them e.g. http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/. You also have some resources on the [DBpedia site](http://dbpedia.org/About). Also plenty of end user tools, check out [Visor](http://visor.psi.enakting.org/) and [VisualDataWeb.org](http://www.visualdataweb.org/tools.php).